# ¿Cómo eliminar un conjunto de datos de un arreglo en c++?

Tags: c++, array

Tengo un programa que tiene un `struct` de la siguiente forma:

```
struct deudores{
int NRR;
float deuda;
char nombre[30], domicilio[30], sexo [1];
}deudor[5];
```

Solo puedo recibir 5 registros de datos en este caso estoy manejando deudores, registro 5 datos que están compuestos de la siguiente forma:

```
void Agregar(){
if (cont<5){
    cout<<":::Agregar Deudor:::"<<endl;
    deudor[cont].NRR = cont + 1;
    cout<<"Nombre: ";
    cin>>deudor[cont].nombre;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Domicilio: ";
    cin>>deudor[cont].domicilio;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Sexo(H/M): ";
    cin>>deudor[cont].sexo;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Deuda: ";
    cin>>deudor[cont].deuda;
    cin.ignore();
    cont++;
    cout<<"\nDeudor registrado correctamente\n"<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
else{
    cout<<"\nNo hay espacio disponible\n"<<endl;
    system ("pause");
  }
}
```

Pero mi problema está al momento de eliminar, ya que si yo tengo 5 datos registrados los cuales tienen un `NRR(ID)` del 1 al 5 y eliminó el dato numero 1 y hago un `cont--;` que cont es mi contador de registros, el registro número 1 queda con valores 0 pero se elimina el registro número 5. Mi método a eliminar es el siguiente:

```
void Eliminar(){
if (cont!=0){
    bool band=false;
    int dato;

    cout<<"Ingresa el NRR a Eliminar: ";
    cin>>dato;

    for (int i=0; i<cont; i++){
        if(dato == deudor[i].NRR){
            cout<<":::Datos a Eliminar:::"<<endl;
            cout << "========================" << endl;
            cout<<"NRR: "<<deudor[i].NRR<<endl;
            cout<<"Nombre: "<<deudor[i].nombre<<endl;
            cout<<"Domicilio: "<<deudor[i].domicilio<<endl;
            cout<<"Sexo: "<<deudor[i].sexo<<endl;
            cout<<"Deuda: "<<deudor[i].deuda<<endl;
            cout << "========================" << endl;
            cout << "\nDeudor eliminado correctamente\n" << endl;
            system ("pause");

            band=true;

            deudor[i].NRR = 0;
            deudor[i].nombre[0]='\0';
            *deudor[i].domicilio=0;
            *deudor[i].sexo=0;
            deudor[i].deuda=0.0;

            cont--;
        }
    }
    if(band==false){
        cout<<"\nEl deudor ingresado no existe\n"<<endl;
        system("pause");
    }
}
else{
  cout<<"\nNo hay deudores registrados\n"<<endl;
  system ("pause");
}
}
```

Espero me de a entender en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu idea es que al agregar un elemento este se ingrese siempre al final de la lista, al eliminar un registro tienes que desplazar los siguientes para que el hueco quede en última posición:

```
// Localizamos la posición del registro a borrar
int aBorrar = -1;
for (int i=0; i<cont; i++){
  if (dato == deudor[i].NRR)
  {
    aBorrar = i;
    break;
  }
}

if( aBorrar < 0 )
  // No existe el registro
else
{
  // Para borrarlo desplazamos los registros siguientes una posición
  for(int i=aBorrar+1; i<cont; i++)
    deudor[i-1] = deudor[i];
  cont--;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias es lo que me habían mencionado, desplazando los elementos y no sabia como hacerlo. Gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 5):

#### Problema.

Tienes un arreglo estático de tamaño 5 `deudores`. Al ser el tamaño estático no puedes quitar y poner registros con total libertad si no que debes limitarte a reutilizar las posiciones del arreglo. Esto puede ser problemático si te eliminan posiciones aleatorias y/o no consecutivas del arreglo.

#### Solución 1: Usa [contenedores stl](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Olvida el arreglo de 5 `deudores` y usa un contenedor de datos adecuado a la tarea que quieres realizar. En tu caso requieres inserciones y borrados en posiciones aleatorias de tu colección de registros, así que la elección es [`std::list`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list):

> `std::list` es un contenedor que soporta inserción y borrado rápido de elementos en cualquier parte del contenedor.

El código podría quedar como:

```
struct deudor{ // Nombre en singular, no en plural.
    int NRR;
    float deuda;
    char nombre[30], domicilio[30], sexo [1];
}; // Ya no es un arreglo

std::list<deudor> deudores; // Contenedor de deudores

void Agregar(){
if (deudores.size() < 5){ // Queda espacio?
    deudor nuevo{}; // Nuevo deudor a anyadir.
    cout<<":::Agregar Deudor:::\n";
    nuevo.NRR = cont + 1;

    cout<<"Nombre: ";    cin>>nuevo.nombre;    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Domicilio: "; cin>>nuevo.domicilio; cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Sexo(H/M): "; cin>>nuevo.sexo;      cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Deuda: ";     cin>>nuevo.deuda;     cin.ignore();

    ++cont;
    deudores.push_back(nuevo); // <-- Se anyade el nuevo deudor.
    cout<<"\nDeudor registrado correctamente\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
else{
    cout<<"\nNo hay espacio disponible\n\n";
    system ("pause");
  }
}

void Eliminar(){
if (!deudores.empty()){ // Si no esta vacio...
    int dato;

    cout<<"Ingresa el NRR a Eliminar: ";
    cin>>dato;

    // Buscamos en la coleccion...
    auto encontrado = std::find_if(deudores.begin(), deudores.end(),
    [dato](const deudor &d){ // Lambda de busqueda
        return dato == d.NRR;
    });

    if (encontrado != deudores.end()){
        cout<<":::Datos a Eliminar:::\n";
        cout << "========================\n";
        cout<<"NRR: "       <<encontrado->NRR<<endl;
        cout<<"Nombre: "    <<encontrado->nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Domicilio: " <<encontrado->domicilio<<endl;
        cout<<"Sexo: "      <<encontrado->sexo<<endl;
        cout<<"Deuda: "     <<encontrado->deuda<<endl;
        cout << "========================\n";
        deudores.erase(encontrado); // Borramos el deudor.
        cout << "\nDeudor eliminado correctamente\n\n";

        cont--;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"\nEl deudor ingresado no existe\n\n";
    }
}
else{
  cout<<"\nNo hay deudores registrados\n"<<endl;
}
system ("pause");
}
```

He intentado conservar to código lo máximo posible pero usando funciones y contenedores STL no necesitas limitar los registros a 5. Las inserciones siempre se hacen al final ([`push_back`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back)) y el [borrado](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) se puede hacer en cualquier posición sin problemas incluso eliminando más de un registro.

#### Solución 2: Guarda un registro de posiciones libres.

Si no quieres olvidarte del arreglo, necesitarás saber en qué posiciones se puede o no pueden escribir datos, para ello usa un arreglo (del mismo tamaño) de posiciones libres, el código podría quedar como:

```
constexpr unsigned MAX_REGISTROS{5};

struct deudor{ // Nombre en singular, no en plural.
    int NRR;
    float deuda;
    char nombre[30], domicilio[30], sexo [1];
}deudores[MAX_REGISTROS] {};

// Recuerda que posiciones estan disponibles para ser escritas
// inicialmente lo estan todas.
bool posicion_libre[MAX_REGISTROS] {};

void Agregar(){
// Buscamos la primera posicion libre
auto primero_libre = std::find_if(std::begin(posicion_ocupada), std::end(posicion_ocupada),
    [](bool ocupado) { 
        return !ocupado;
    });

    if (primero_libre != std::end(posicion_ocupada)){ // Hay alguna posicion libre?
    // Calculamos la posicion libre
    auto posicion = std::distance(std::begin(posicion_ocupada), primero_libre);
    std::cout << posicion << " esta libre--------------\n";
    cout<<":::Agregar Deudor:::\n";
    // Apuntamos al deudor en la posicion libre
    deudor &nuevo = deudores[posicion];
    nuevo.NRR = cont + 1;

    cout<<"Nombre: ";    cin>>nuevo.nombre;    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Domicilio: "; cin>>nuevo.domicilio; cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Sexo(H/M): "; cin>>nuevo.sexo;      cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Deuda: ";     cin>>nuevo.deuda;     cin.ignore();

    ++cont;
    // Marcamos la posicion como ocupada
    posicion_ocupada[posicion] = true;
    cout<<"\nDeudor registrado correctamente\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
else{
    cout<<"\nNo hay espacio disponible\n\n";
    system ("pause");
  }
}

void Eliminar()
{
if (cont!=0)
{
    int dato;

    cout<<"Ingresa el NRR a Eliminar: ";
    cin>>dato;

    // Buscamos en la coleccion...
    auto encontrado = std::find_if(std::begin(deudores), std::end(deudores),
    [dato](const deudor &d){ // Lambda de busqueda
        return dato == d.NRR;
    });

    if (encontrado != std::end(deudores))
    {
        // Calculamos la posicion a eliminar
        auto posicion = std::distance(std::begin(deudores), encontrado);
        cout<<":::Datos a Eliminar:::\n";
        cout << "========================\n";
        cout<<"NRR: "       <<encontrado->NRR<<endl;
        cout<<"Nombre: "    <<encontrado->nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"Domicilio: " <<encontrado->domicilio<<endl;
        cout<<"Sexo: "      <<encontrado->sexo<<endl;
        cout<<"Deuda: "     <<encontrado->deuda<<endl;
        cout << "========================\n";
        posicion_ocupada[posicion] = false; // Marcamos la posicion como libre.
        cout << "\nDeudor eliminado correctamente\n\n";

        cont--;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"\nEl deudor ingresado no existe\n\n";
    }
}
else{
        cout<<"\nNo hay deudores registrados\n"<<endl;
    }
}
```

En esta versión el `deudor` nunca se borra si no que se marca como "*posición disponible*", el llevar la cuenta de que posiciones están disponibles es vital para llevar bien los registros porque cabe la posibilidad de que se borren registros alternos.

#### Problemas de estilo.

Tienes una serie de problemas en tu código que deberías tener en cuenta:

- No uses el plural para una estructura que contiene datos individuales: Es muy confuso que `deudores` sea un único deudor mientras que `deudor` son varios, intercambia los nombres.
- No uses arreglos de caracteres para guardar textos de longitud variable: No sólo puede ser un desperdicio de espacio (si el usuario se llama Ana desperdicias 27 posiciones de `char deudor::nombre[30]`) si no que además puede dar lugar a errores en tiempo de ejecución si el [nombre es más largo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brfxxccxxmnpcccclllmmnprxvclmnckssqlbb11116) que la longitud del arreglo. Lo mismo para el domicilio. Usa `std::string`.
- ¿Un arreglo de tamaño uno? ¿En serio?: Usa un solo char.
- Usa una constante para definir el tamaño máximo de tu arreglo: De esta manera si necesitas cambiar el tamaño tan sólo deberás modificar la constante no buscar el valor `5` por todo el código.

Comment: Realmente por lo que no utilice una lista o alguna otra alternativa fue porque estrictamente nos pidieron hacerlo de esa forma, y de igual forma muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pero me voy por la mas viable que es el desplazar los elementos.

Comment: @EduardoJavierMaldonado "*estrictamente nos pidieron hacerlo de esa forma*" la próxima vez no olvides mencionarlo ;)

Comment: Jajaja @PaperBirdMaster muy bueno lo de "el nombre más largo" xd